# execute permission was denied on the object 'sp_enable_sql_debug' database master

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to debug my stored procedure, but it's saying the permission error.

> execute permission was denied on the object 'sp_enable_sql_debug' database master Microsoft SQL Server, Error:300

Comment: I received this same error from a SQL user that accidentally hit Debug instead of Execute.  The fix was to hit Execute.  The permissions were fine.

Answer (score 2):

This procedure normally requires the sysadmin permissions to run, because it exposes system processes to the account.  The easiest way to solve this (although not the ideal one) is to get sysadmin privileges on that environment.

Comment: I have full permission, but it's not working.

Comment: Full permission, like database owner or are you a member of the sysadmin group?